# Cannot spy on angular.element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, spy

I have one Jasmine test that is continously failing due to a `spyOn` not executing.

The following test will automatically fail:

```
it('simple test', function() {
    spyOn(angular, 'element');
});
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'angular.element(handle.elem).off')
        at /Users/geoff/Project/www/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1946
        at /Users/geoff/Project/www/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1977
```

This error only seems to happen with `angular.element`. `spy`ing on other `angular` methods such as `angular.copy` and `angular.forEach` do not throw this error. I am using Jasmine 2.0 and Angular ~1.3. Any advice on fixing this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you reconstruct your issue in a plunkr or jsFiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allow access to the real object.

```
spyOn(angular, 'element').and.callThrough();
```

The code is trying to access a property on the return value, but the spy is not returning anything. You can't access `.off` on an undefined object!